# How can I perform multiplication without the '*' operator?

Tags: java, c++, c, bit-manipulation

I was just going through some basic stuff as I am learning C. I came upon a question to multiply a number by 7 without using the * operator. Basically it's like this

```
      (x << 3) - x;
```

Now I know about basic bit manipulation operations, but I can't get how do you multiply a number by any other odd number without using the * operator? Is there a general algorithm for this?

Comment: that's (8*x)-x or IOW 7x

Comment: Note that most compilers already optimize things like this. I.e., turning 15*x into ((x<<4)-x))

Comment: Algebra :) - (x << 3) - x = 8 * x - x = (8 - 1) * x = 7 * x
The trick is that x << 3 == x * 2^3 == 8

Comment: Just use the `*` operator; that's what it's for.  This is nearly a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991341/multiply-by-7-in-efficient-way/7991412).  Note that `(x<<3) - x` can overflow for some values of `x` where the simpler and clearer `x * 7` won't.

Comment: Related  [Java only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639366) duplicate here.

Answer (score 59):

Think about how you multiply in decimal using pencil and paper:

```
  12
x 26
----
  72
 24
----
 312
```

What does multiplication look like in binary?

```
   0111
x  0101
-------
   0111
  0000
 0111
-------
 100011
```

Notice anything?  Unlike multiplication in decimal, where you need to memorize the "times table," when multiplying in binary, you are always multiplying one of the terms by either 0 or 1 before writing it down in the list addends.  There's no times table needed.  If the digit of the second term is 1, you add in the first term.  If it's 0, you don't.  Also note how the addends are progressively shifted over to the left.

If you're unsure of this, do a few binary multiplications on paper.  When you're done, convert the result back to decimal and see if it's correct.  After you've done a few, I think you'll get the idea how binary multiplication can be implemented using shifts and adds.

Answer (score 25):

Everyone is overlooking the obvious. No multiplication is involved:

```
10^(log10(A) + log10(B))
```

Comment: Which in C would be `exp(log(A) + log(B))`.

Comment: I suppose you're being sarcastic, but if you're not, have you ever looked at source code for logn?

Comment: I looked at it as more of a history lesson then being sarcastic. People today tend to forget we did do thing before we had computers or even electronic calculators. I've seen to many engineers and programs who accept the result from the "magic box" without understanding how it works. No one can know everything, but we should understand as much as we can. I know the general algorithm for computing logs, but I admit I have not studied them in great depth. They od involve shifting which is multiplying in binary as many people have pointed out. Not unexpected, early CPUS can only add and shift.

Comment: Even many modern CPUs (small, low-power ones) can't multiply or divide. Why waste microcode on that when it can easily be done in software?

Comment: The old slide rule implementation!  Gotta love the scene in Apollo 13 where 10 engineers are simultaneously doing a calculation on their slide rules - multi-core at its infancy!

Comment: Shame log10 in C doesn't support negative numbers (complex/imaginary numbers, etc). Wolfram Alpha handles them very well!

Comment: @jimc: in the best of the cases (CORDIC), logs and exps are computed using shifts and adds only, but requires at least one of each per bit of accuracy; this is more costly than a plain multiply. In other implementations, they require... a lot of multiplies.

Answer (score 23):

The question says:

> multiply a number by 7 without using * operator

This doesn't use `*`:

```
 number / (1 / 7)
```

**Edit:**
This compiles and works fine in C:

```
 int number,result;
 number = 8;
 result = number / (1. / 7);
 printf("result is %d\n",result);
```

Comment: +1 for the idea, but it won't work in Java: `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` since (1 / 7) is done by integer division (workaround is easy)

Comment: actually it won't work in c either!  I'm pretty sure you'd get a core dump if you ran that line :).

Comment: Will probably fail for some values due to rounding.  Will fail if your `int` is 64 bits and `number` is greater than 2^51 or so...

Comment: When you are assigning the result to `result` variable, the fractional part is truncated. The means that if the reslt is imprecise (often happens with FP arithmetics), the truncation might easily produce an incorrect result - off by 1.

Comment: @Chris Dodd, AndreyT - True, FP can byte you. My point is the idea, not the implementation.

Comment: You still need an explicit cast to convert the `double` result to an `int`.

Comment: @Loadmaster: You don't need an explicit cast to convert `double` to `int`. This is a standard conversion in both C and C++, so no cast is needed. The only reason people might use an explicit cast is to suppress some annoying compiler warnings.

Comment: JAVA Version: double result = paramThird / ( 1. / (paramFirst / (1. / paramSecond)));
System.out.println("result : " + result);

Answer (score 19):

An integer left shift is multiplying by 2, provided it doesn't overflow. Just add or subtract as appropriate once you get close.

Answer (score 17):

```
int multiply(int multiplicand, int factor)
{
    if (factor == 0) return 0;

    int product = multiplicand;
    for (int ii = 1; ii < abs(factor); ++ii) {
        product += multiplicand;
    }

    return factor >= 0 ? product : -product;
}
```

You wanted multiplication without `*`, you got it, pal!

Comment: Wow, thanks dkantowitz. I had no idea! +10 to you my good man!
(oh, and *nothing* in the question necessitates bit shifting, but I'm sure you realized that too.)

Comment: -1. This code is broken since instead of adding `multiplicand` to a running sum (initially 0), it adds `multiplicand` to itself, which results in a multiplication of `multiplicand` by `2^(abs(factor)-1)*sgn(factor)` instead of by `factor`.

Answer (score 12):

It's easy to avoid the '*' operator:

```
mov eax, 1234h
mov edx, 5678h
imul edx
```

No '*' in sight. Of course, if you wanted to get into the spirit of it, you could also use the trusty old shift and add algorithm:

```
mult proc
; Multiplies eax by ebx and places result in edx:ecx
    xor ecx, ecx
    xor edx, edx
mul1:
    test ebx, 1
    jz  mul2
    add ecx, eax
    adc edx, 0
mul2:
    shr ebx, 1
    shl eax, 1
    test ebx, ebx
    jnz  mul1
done:
    ret
mult endp
```

Of course, with modern processors, all (?) have multiplication instructions, but back when the [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) was shiny and new, code like this saw real use.

Comment: That's not fair, the question is tagged `c`, `c++`, and `java`  ;)

Comment: @dreamlax: Quite true -- and if somebody reverse engineers the algorithm from assembly code to get an A on their C, C++ or Java homework, I'm willing to believe they probably earned the grade...

Comment: My first home computer was a TRS-80, sporting a zippy 1.7MHz Z80, and I typed in a lot of multiplication routines like this.  Turned out the fastest way was to do as many 8x16 bit multiplications as necessary, and add them up.

Comment: Gotta love x86's LEA instruction... shift and add in a single instruction :)

Comment: Even many modern CPUs (small, low-power ones) can't multiply or divide. Why waste microcode on that when it can easily be done in software?

Answer (score 10):

Mathematically speaking, multiplication *distributes* over addition.  Essentially, this means:

> x * (a + b + c ...) = (x * a) + (x * b) + (x * c) ...

Any real number (in your case `7`), can be presented as a series of additions (such as `8 + (-1)`, since subtraction is really just addition going the wrong way). This allows you to represent any single multiplication statement as an equivalent series of multiplication statements, which will come up with the same result:

```
x * 7
= x * (8 + (-1))
= (x * 8) + (x * (-1))
= (x * 8) - (x * 1)
= (x * 8) - x
```

The **bitwise shift** operator essentially just multiplies or divides a number by a power of 2. So long as your equation is only dealing with such values, bit shifting can be used to replace all occurrence of the multiplication operator.

> (x * 8) - x = (x * 2<sup>3</sup>) - x = (x << 3) - x

A similar strategy can be used on any other integer, and it makes no difference whether it's odd or even.

Answer (score 8):

It is the same as `x*8-x = x*(8-1) = x*7`

Answer (score 8):

Any number, odd or even, can be expressed as a sum of powers of two. For example,

```
     1   2   4   8
------------------
 1 = 1
 2 = 0 + 2
 3 = 1 + 2
 4 = 0 + 0 + 4
 5 = 1 + 0 + 4
 6 = 0 + 2 + 4
 7 = 1 + 2 + 4
 8 = 0 + 0 + 0 + 8
11 = 1 + 2 + 0 + 8
```

So, you can multiply x by any number by performing the right set of shifts and adds.

```
 1x = x
 2x = 0 + x<<1
 3x = x + x<<1
 4x = 0 +  0   + x<<2
 5x = x +  0   + x<<2
11x = x + x<<1 +   0  + x<<3
```

Comment: Useful! But how about scenarios similar to the OP's, such as multiplying by shifting and *subtracting* too? i.e. 6x = (x << 3) - (x << 1) etc?

Comment: I thought the only rule was to avoid the `*` operator.

Comment: Also, your table is a little out, 2x is (x << 1), and 4x is (x << 2) etc.

Comment: @dreamlax: a factor with 2 sequential `1`s in the multiplicand can be replaced with the same number of operations doing a subtraction. With more than 2 sequential `1`s, subtracting uses even less operations.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes down to it, multiplication by a positive integer can be done like this:

```
int multiply(int a, int b) {
  int ret = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<b; i++) {
    ret += b;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Efficient? Hardly. But it's correct (factoring in limits on ints and so forth).

So using a left-shift is just a shortcut for multiplying by 2. But once you get to the highest power-of-2 under `b` you just add `a` the necessary number of times, so:

```
int multiply(int a, int b) {
  int ret = a;
  int mult = 1;
  while (mult <= b) {
    ret <<= 1;
    mult <<= 1;
  }
  while (mult < b) {
    ret += a;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

or something close to that.

To put it another way, to multiply by 7.

- Left shift by 2 (times 4). Left shift 3 is 8 which is >7;
- Add `b` 3 times.

Comment: In your first example, you either mean: `ret += a;` or `i < a`.  You should mention that it assumes non-negatives integers in the "and so forth".

Comment: I dont get it....What do we add 3 times?? Like if the the number is 7 to be mulitplied by 7, like I wrote, it is left shift by 3 and subtract 7, the result is 49. What exactly is b? Pardon my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

One evening, I found that I was extremely bored, and cooked this up:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned int uint32;

uint32 add(uint32 a, uint32 b) {
    do {
        uint32 s = a ^ b;
        uint32 c = a & b;
        a = s;
        b = c << 1;
    } while (a & b)
    return (a | b)
}

uint32 mul(uint32 a, uint32 b) {
    uint32 total = 0;
    do {
        uint32 s1 = a & (-(b & 1))
        b >>= 1; a <<= 1;
        total = add(s1, total)
    } while (b)
    return total;
}

int main(void) {
    using namespace std;
    uint32 a, b;

    cout << "Enter two numbers to be multiplied: ";
    cin >> a >> b;

    cout << "Total: " << mul(a,b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code above should be quite self-explanatory, as I tried to keep it as simple as possible. It should work, more or less, the way a CPU might perform these operations. The only bug I'm aware of is that `a` is not permitted to be greater than 32,767 and `b` is not permitted to be large enough to overflow `a` (that is, multiply overflow is not handled, so 64-bit results are not possible). It should even work with negative numbers, provided the inputs are appropriately `reinterpret_cast<>`.

Comment: `The code above should be quite self-explanatory` trust me, it's not.

Answer (score 4):

O(log(b)) method

```
public int multiply_optimal(int a, int b) {

    if (a == 0 || b == 0)
        return 0;
    if (b == 1)
        return a;
    if ((b & 1) == 0)
        return multiply_optimal(a + a, b >> 1);
    else
        return a + multiply_optimal(a + a, b >> 1);

}
```

The resursive code works as follows:
Base case:
if either of the number is 0 ,product is 0.
if b=1, product =a.

If b is even:
ab can be written as 2a(b/2)
2a(b/2)=(a+a)*(b/2)=(a+a)*(b>>1) where'>>' arithematic right shift operator in java.

If b is odd:
ab can be written as a+a(b-1)
a+a(b-1)=a+2a(b-1)/2=a+(a+a)(b-1)/2=a+(a+a)((b-1)>>1)
Since b is odd (b-1)/2=b/2=b>>1
So ab=a+(2a*(b>>1))
NOTE:each recursive call b is halved => O(log(b))

Answer (score 3):

```
unsigned int Multiply(unsigned int m1, unsigned int m2)
{
    unsigned int numBits = sizeof(unsigned int) * 8; // Not part of the core algorithm
    unsigned int product = 0;
    unsigned int mask = 1;
    for(int i =0; i < numBits; ++i, mask = mask << 1)
    {
        if(m1 & mask)
        {
            product += (m2 << i);
        }
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Rather than using `* 8` you could just use `<< 3` :)

Answer (score 2):

@Wang, that's a good generalization. But here is a slightly faster version.  But it assumes no overflow and a is non-negative.

```
int mult(int a, int b){
    int p=1;
    int rv=0;
    for(int i=0; a >= p && i < 31; i++){
        if(a & p){
            rv += b;
        }
        p = p << 1;
        b = b << 1;
    }

    return rv;
}
```

It will loop at most 1+log_2(a) times. Could be faster if you swap a and b when a > b.

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned int Multiply( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    int ret = 0;
    // For each bit in b
    for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {

        // If that bit is not equal to zero
        if (( b & (1 << i)) != 0) {

            // Add it to our return value
            ret += a << i;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I avoided the sign bit, because it's kind of not the subject of the post. This is an implementation of what [Wayne Conrad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069488/multiply-without-operator/2069539#2069539) said basically. [Here is another problem is you want to try more low level math operations.](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=13) [Project Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Euler) is cool!

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class MultiplyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger bigInt1 = new BigInteger("5");
        BigInteger bigInt2 = new BigInteger("8");
        System.out.println(bigInt1.multiply(bigInt2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shift and add doesn't work (even with sign extension) when the multiplicand is negative. Signed multiplication has to be done using [Booth encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth's_multiplication_algorithm):

Starting from the [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit), a change from 0 to 1 is -1; a change from 1 to 0 is 1, otherwise 0. There is also an implicit extra bit 0 below the LSB.

For example, the number 5 (0101) will be encoded as: (1)(-1)(1)(-1). You can verify this is correct:

5 = 2^3 - 2^2 + 2 -1

This algorithm also works with negative numbers in 2's complement form:

-1 in 4-bit 2's complement is 1111. Using the Booth algorithm: (1)(0)(0)(0)(-1), where there is no space for the leftmost bit 1 so we get: (0)(0)(0)(-1) which is -1.

```
/* Multiply two signed integers using the Booth algorithm */
int booth(int x, int y)
{
    int prev_bit = 0;
    int result = 0;

    while (x != 0) {
        int current_bit = x & 0x1;
        if (prev_bit & ~current_bit) {
            result += y;
        } else if (~prev_bit & current_bit) {
            result -= y;
        }

        prev_bit = current_bit;

        x = static_cast<unsigned>(x) >> 1;
        y <<= 1;
    }

    if (prev_bit)
        result += y;

    return result;
}
```

The above code does not check for overflow. Below is a slightly modified version that multiplies two 16 bit numbers and returns a 32 bit number so it never overflows:

```
/* Multiply two 16-bit signed integers using the Booth algorithm */
/* Returns a 32-bit signed integer */
int32_t booth(int16_t x, int16_t y)
{
    int16_t prev_bit = 0;
    int16_t sign_bit = (x >> 16) & 0x1;
    int32_t result = 0;
    int32_t y1 = static_cast<int32_t>(y);

    while (x != 0) {
        int16_t current_bit = x & 0x1;
        if (prev_bit & ~current_bit) {
            result += y1;
        } else if (~prev_bit & current_bit) {
            result -= y1;
        }

        prev_bit = current_bit;

        x = static_cast<uint16_t>(x) >> 1;
        y1 <<= 1;
    }

    if (prev_bit & ~sign_bit)
        result += y1;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#:

```
private static string Multi(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0 || b == 0)
        return "0";

    bool isnegative = false;

    if (a < 0 || b < 0)
    {
        isnegative = true;

        a = Math.Abs(a);

        b = Math.Abs(b);
    }

    int sum = 0;

    if (a > b)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
        {
            sum += a;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
        {
            sum += b;
        }
    }

    if (isnegative == true)
        return "-" + sum.ToString();
    else
        return sum.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the log function:

```
public static final long multiplyUsingShift(int a, int b) {
    int absA = Math.abs(a);
    int absB = Math.abs(b);

    //Find the 2^b which is larger than "a" which turns out to be the 
    //ceiling of (Log base 2 of b) == numbers of digits to shift
    double logBase2 = Math.log(absB) / Math.log(2);
    long bits = (long)Math.ceil(logBase2);

    //Get the value of 2^bits
    long biggerInteger = (int)Math.pow(2, bits);

    //Find the difference of the bigger integer and "b"
    long difference = biggerInteger - absB;

    //Shift "bits" places to the left
    long result = absA<<bits;

    //Subtract the "difference" "a" times
    int diffLoop = Math.abs(a);
    while (diffLoop>0) {
        result -= difference;
        diffLoop--;
    }

    return (a>0&&b>0 || a<0&&b<0)?result:-result;
}
```

If you cannot use the log function:

```
public static final long multiplyUsingShift(int a, int b) {
    int absA = Math.abs(a);
    int absB = Math.abs(b);

    //Get the number of bits for a 2^(b+1) larger number
    int bits = 0;
    int bitInteger = absB;
    while (bitInteger>0) {
        bitInteger /= 2;
        bits++;
    }

    //Get the value of 2^bit
    long biggerInteger = (int)Math.pow(2, bits);

    //Find the difference of the bigger integer and "b"
    long difference = biggerInteger - absB;

    //Shift "bits" places to the left
    long result = absA<<bits;

    //Subtract the "difference" "a" times
    int diffLoop = absA;
    while (diffLoop>0) {
        result -= difference;
        diffLoop--;
    }

    return (a>0&&b>0 || a<0&&b<0)?result:-result;
}
```

I found this to be more efficient:

```
public static final long multiplyUsingShift(int a, int b) {
    int absA = Math.abs(a);
    int absB = Math.abs(b);

    long result = 0L;
    while (absA>0) {
        if ((absA&1)>0) result += absB; //Is odd
        absA >>= 1;
        absB <<= 1;
    }

    return (a>0&&b>0 || a<0&&b<0)?result:-result;
}
```

and yet another way.

```
public static final long multiplyUsingLogs(int a, int b) {
    int absA = Math.abs(a);
    int absB = Math.abs(b);
    long result = Math.round(Math.pow(10, (Math.log10(absA)+Math.log10(absB))));
    return (a>0&&b>0 || a<0&&b<0)?result:-result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**JAVA:**
Considering the fact, that every number can be splitted into powers of two:

```
1 = 2 ^ 0
2 = 2 ^ 1
3 = 2 ^ 1 + 2 ^ 0
...
```

We want to get x where:
`x = n * m`
So we can achieve that by doing following steps:

```
1.   while m is greater or equal to 2^pow:
     1.1  get the biggest number pow, such as 2^pow is lower or equal to m
     1.2  multiply n*2^pow and decrease m to m-2^pow
2.   sum the results
```

Sample implementation using recursion:

```
long multiply(int n, int m) {
    int pow = 0;
    while (m >= (1 << ++pow)) ;
    pow--;
    if (m == 1 << pow) return (n << pow);
    return (n << pow) + multiply(n, m - (1 << pow));
}
```

I got this question in last job interview and this answer was accepted.
EDIT: solution for positive numbers

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest C99/C11 solution for positive numbers:

```
unsigned multiply(unsigned x, unsigned y) { return sizeof(char[x][y]); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thinking-outside-the-box answer:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(123);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(2);
BigDecimal result = a.multiply(b);
System.out.println(result.intValue());
```

Comment: How does this work in "C"?  I think you may have misread the original question.

Comment: @S.Robins: use libgmp for exapmle.  mpz_mul (mpz_t rop, mpz_t op1, mpz_t op2)

Answer (score 0):

Loop it. Run a loop seven times and iterate by the number you are multiplying with seven.

Pseudocode:

```
total = 0
multiply = 34

loop while i < 7

    total = total + multiply

endloop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.amit.string;

// Here I am passing two values, 7 and 3 and method getResult() will
// return 21 without use of any operator except the increment operator, ++.
//
public class MultiplyTwoNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 7;
        int b = 3;
        System.out.println(new MultiplyTwoNumber().getResult(a, b));
    }

    public int getResult(int i, int j) {
        int result = 0;

        // Check for loop logic it is key thing it will go 21 times
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            for (int p = 0; p < j; p++) {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: And please be careful about the indentation of code. If the posted code is hard to read then it is lesser helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int multiply(int a, int b) 
{
    int temp = 0;
    if (b == 0) return 0;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < abs(b); ++ii) {
        temp = temp + a;
    }

    return b >= 0 ? temp : -temp;
}

public static int abs(int val) {

    return val>=0 ? val : -val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter value of A -> ");
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    double j=s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter value of B -> ");
    Scanner p=new Scanner(System.in);
    double k=p.nextInt();
    double m=(1/k);
    double l=(j/m);
    System.out.print("Multiplication of A & B=> "+l);
}
```

Comment: This approach has been suggested several years ago in answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2069878/2564301. Other than being in Java, it does not seem to add to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript approach for positive numbers

```
function recursiveMultiply(num1, num2){
    const bigger = num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2; 
    const smaller = num1 <= num2 ? num1 : num2; 
    const indexIncrement = 1;
    const resultIncrement = bigger;

    return recursiveMultiplyHelper(bigger, smaller, 0, indexIncrement, resultIncrement)
}

function recursiveMultiplyHelper(num1, num2, index, indexIncrement, resultIncrement){
    let result = 0;
    if (index === num2){
        return result;
    } 

    if ((index+indexIncrement+indexIncrement) >= num2){
        indexIncrement = 1;
        resultIncrement = num1;
    } else{
        indexIncrement += indexIncrement;
        resultIncrement += resultIncrement;
    }

    result = recursiveMultiplyHelper(num1, num2, (index+indexIncrement), indexIncrement, resultIncrement);
    result += resultIncrement;
    console.log(num1, num2, index, result);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the normal multiplication method we use

```
         1101 x        =>13
         0101          =>5
---------------------
         1101
        0000
       1101
      0000
===================        
      1000001 .        => 65
```

Writing the same above in the code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int multiply(int a, int b){
    int res = 0,count =0;
    while(b>0) {
        if(b & 0x1)
            res = res + (a << count);
        b = b>>1;
        count++;
    }
    return res;
}
int main() {
    printf("Sum of x+y = %d", multiply(5,10));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Very simple, pal... Each time when you left shift a number it means you are multiplying the number by 2 which means the answer is (x<<3)-x.

Answer (score -1):

To multiply of two numbers without `*` operator:

```
int mul(int a,int b) {
    int result = 0;
    if(b > 0) {
        for(int i=1;i<=b;i++){
            result += a;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Ugly and slow and untested, but...

```
int mult(a,b){
    int i, rv=0;
    for(i=0; i < 31; ++i){
        if(a & 1<<i){
            rv += b << i;
        }
    }
    if(a & 1<<31){ // two's complement
        rv -= b<<31;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: You could at least test it before submitting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: a & i << i. Think about that for a little bit.

Comment: Adam: Didn't have a compiler, I'm afraid. But point taken. I won't do that again.

Bear: Yep, I think that was supposed to be 1<<i. This is why Adam is telling me to test my code.