# Multiply by 7 in efficient way

Tags: c

I recently encountered the following interview question:

> How can you multiply a number by 7 in an efficient and optimized way?

I know that I can multiply by 8 (or left-shift by three bits) and then subtract the original value:

```
num = (num << 3) - num;
```

but are there any other solutions.

Comment: I'm curious, are you saying that multiplying by 8 is faster than multiplying by 7?

Comment: @miahelf Can be, by using bit shift. But you have to decrement with the  multiplier not just 1.

Comment: What do you mean multiply by 8 and decrement 1. It should be decremented by the multiplier. Also can you mention, in what terms efficiency is compared with here?

Comment: I'm guessing that multiplying by 8 would be implemented as 3 shift operations, since 8 is 2^3.

Comment: :D I am sorry for the mistake, post updated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get a multiple of 7 in an efficient way:

```
7
```

7 is a multiple of 7.  That answers the question you asked, but I'm sure it doesn't answer the question you mean to ask.

*EDIT: The above is based on the question's original title,which I've just corrected.*

To multiply *by* 7 efficiently, just write, for example:

```
x * 7
```

and invoke your compiler with optimization.  Let the compiler figure out whether a single MUL instruction or something like `(x<<3) - x` is more efficient *for the current machine*.

There's yet another implicit question here: what answer was the interviewer looking for?  I *hope* that "let the compiler worry about it" would be an acceptable answer.  `(x<<3) - x` is probably the most obvious micro-optimization -- but it can yield incorrect answers if `x<<3` overflows, and depending on the system it might be slower than a MUL instruction.

(If I were the interviewer, I'd be more impressed by a good explanation and understanding of the issues than by any specific answer.)

**EDIT**

On further thought, the kinds of micro-optimizations that have been discussed here *might* be useful if you know more about the possible values of `x` than the compiler does.  If you know, because of the nature of your program's logic, that `x` will always be in the range 0..10, then a lookup table could easily be faster than a multiply operation.  Or if you know that `x` is in that range 99% of the time, a lookup table with a fallback to an actual multiplication might be just the thing.

But if the compiler's analysis of your program flow doesn't allow it to *prove* that `x` is always in that range, then it can't perform this kind of optimization.

But such circumstances are very rare.  And when your code runs in a new environment where `x` can be 11 (perhaps it's running on a device with a larger display), *kaboom*.  And the performance improvement very likely wasn't significant in the first place.

There are times when micro-optimization is appropriate, but there is a substantial cost in development and testing time.  Do it only if actual *measurements* indicate that it's worth it.

Comment: Nitpick: `<<` has lower precedence than `-`. So change it to `(x << 3) - x`.

Answer (score 16):

For a limited range, you can use a lookup table:

```
static unsigned int mult7[] = {0, 7, 14, 21, ...};
unsigned int three = 3;
unsigned int twenty_one = mult7[three];
```

This may *sound* silly (and it probably is for this specific case) but it's often handy for things where there is a *real* cost to calculation. I'm just not certain that multiplying by seven counts as one of those cases.

For a start, multiplying `x` by 7 (or shifting `x` three bits left then subtracting `x`) is an operation that can be done entirely inside the CPU. With a table lookup, you might see a multiply-by-four (shift two bits left) followed by an add to get the right address, but then you have to access memory to do the actual lookup - even with caching and all the other wondrous tricks current CPUs are capable of, that's probably going to slow things down.

There's also a good chance that your compiler will already know all the tricks about how to multiply fast. If your seven is a constant (or `const int` or equivalent), the compiler will probably already have chosen the fastest way and there's a good chance the compiler writers know a lot more about this sort of stuff than mere mortals :-) <sup>(a)</sup>

But for cases where the calculation cost *is* relatively high, computing the values once and embedding them in your code as a lookup table is one of the standard optimisation strategies (trade off time for space).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Examine the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int mult7 (int num) {
    return num * 7;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf ("%d\n", mult7 (atoi (argv[1])));
    return 0;
}
```

With normal compilation by `gcc`, `mult7` comes out as the shift left three and subtract trick:

```
_mult7:
    pushl   %ebp             ; stack frame setup.
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx    ; get value to edx
    movl    %edx, %eax       ;    and eax.
    sall    $3, %eax         ; eax <- eax * 8.
    subl    %edx, %eax       ; eax <- eax - edx.
    popl    %ebp             ; stack frame teardown and return.
    ret
```

At `-O3` (what I like to call the insane optimisation level), the whole thing is inlined into `main` with:

```
call    _atoi
movl    $LC0, (%esp)

leal    0(,%eax,8), %edx     ; these two are the relevant instructions.
subl    %eax, %edx

movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
call    _printf
```

Note that this inlining action is only possible due to the static nature of the function - if it were visible to the linker, it would have to be maintained as a separate function in case another object file needed to call it.

If you take off the `static`, it does indeed keep it non-inlined with all the stack frame setup and teardown but it at least still uses the (presumably) more efficient trick mentioned below. You *can* get rid of the stack frame code in `gcc` if you use `-fomit-frame-pointer` provided this doesn't adversely affect the code but this is starting to delve into the dark side a little :-)

This trick is to use the `LEA` instruction to set `edx` to `eax * 8` then subtracts `eax` from that. Same theory as the `sall/subl` at normal optimisation, just slightly different mechanics.

Bottom line, *trust your compiler.* If you want to multiply `num` by 7, use the following:

```
num *= 7;
```

The chances are that whatever improvement you get from such an attempted micro-optimisation, you could get a far better improvement by looking at the macro level (algorithm and data structure selection and so forth).

Answer (score 6):

The way I'd do it would be something like

```
num = (num << 3) - num;
```

ie. 2^3 = 8, then subtract the number being multiplied to get a multiple of 7.

I just compiled the following code with gcc:

```
int mul(int num)
{
   return num * 7;
}
```

and this is a gdb dump of what it compiled to:

```
Dump of assembler code for function mul:
   0x00000000004004c4 <+0>:    push   rbp
   0x00000000004004c5 <+1>:    mov    rbp,rsp
   0x00000000004004c8 <+4>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0xa
   0x00000000004004cf <+11>:   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x00000000004004d2 <+14>:   mov    eax,edx
   0x00000000004004d4 <+16>:   shl    eax,0x3
   0x00000000004004d7 <+19>:   sub    eax,edx
   0x00000000004004d9 <+21>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
   0x00000000004004dc <+24>:   pop    rbp
   0x00000000004004dd <+25>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

So seems for my machine shifting left 3 times and then subtracting the number being multiplied is what gcc believes may be optimal.

**EDIT:** Turns out with an optimisation level of at least 1 (`-O1`), gcc uses the `lea` trick:

```
Dump of assembler code for function mul:
   0x00000000004004e0 <+0>: lea    eax,[rdi*8+0x0]
   0x00000000004004e7 <+7>: sub    eax,edi
   0x00000000004004e9 <+9>: ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Do that at a high optimisation level and you'll find `gcc` turns it into something like `int mul(void) { return 70;}` :-) In fact, if you shut off all that stacj frame crud, it can get it down to something like `mov eax,70;ret`.

Comment: @paxdiablo yeah I tried that before and saw smart old gcc was doing that, so just passed `num` to it.

Comment: I'm surprised that it didn't issue a `lea` instruction. Or does that only apply to `+` operations? (whereas this one has a `-`)

Comment: @Mystical yeah I did another test and turns out it likes to do that with optimisations, editing post now.

Comment: One thing, AusC, `return num *= 7;` is probably unnecessary (why multiply num itself by 7 when you're going to throw it away anyway?) - just do `return num * 7;`.

Comment: @paxdiablo, woops, it was previously `int num = 10; num *= 7;` and I just removed the first line so I could pass `num` since gcc was optimising it to just `return 70`. Forgot to edit that line too. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, the most efficient way to multiply by 7 *may* be to use the multiply operator.  It depends on the relative speed of the respective instructions on the target platform.

IMO, a complete answer to such an interview question should also mention the following:

1. This kind of optimization is normally best left to the compiler / compiler writer.  (Indeed, from another answer, it appears that gcc *does* optimize this case.)
2. You (as a programmer) should only spend time on this if 1) there is a real (measurable) performance issue, and 2) your profiler tells you that the statements that you are looking at are performance critical.

---

In his answer. Olaf wrote this:

> "I disagree with Stephen C when he tells you what you should (or shouldn't) do. If everyone did that there'd be no innovations in the software industry."

It would seem that Olaf that doesn't believe one or more of the following:

- that a Software Engineer should give advice,
- that a Software Engineer should *take* advice, or
- that an employee/programmer should avoid wasting the bosses time on pointless hand-optimization.

It is true that if everyone *always* acted on the advice they received there would be less innovation.  But the flip side is that the job in hand *typically* does not require much innovation.  (And it rarely requires hand optimization ...)

Besides, if ignoring advice (best practice) was a virtue, then 75% of software engineers would be spending their time maintaining "goto spaghetti", assembly code or the results of some 1990's fad in design methodology.

So you should at the very least understand the advice, and weigh up the potential consequences of ignoring it.  Like the boss taking a dim view of your "innovating" (or more accurately, time wasting) on his projects.

Comment: We work in a profession where there are few - if any absolutes. As such, there are many areas which are unexplored and simply waiting for curious individuals to dive in. It cannot be assumed that an individual - simply by asking a question - does not know how to distinguish between when - at work or elsewhere - he should or should not dive in. As to "ignoring advice" I've said no such thing. As to the boss' time there are many types of bosses and though some would take the "wasting time" view others might view and handle the situation differently.

Comment: As to "fads in design methodology" 1990's or otherwise, they appear to often result in bloated and slow applications. Client/server apps often place an unnecessary burden on the server resulting in long response times. C# and Java are touted as the answer to all our prayers. I recently came across a Java app consisting of 43000 input files (not all source) and though that is an absolute low (or high) I have understood from other channels that bloatapps are not uncommon. Many managers appear to think that SW development is a methodology problem and that the people factor can be eliminated ...

Comment: ... but the fact is that many projects are staffed with relatively inexperienced individuals who may or may not be up to the task. Some may see development as a short step before becoming managers. Others are in it because it is a profession in demand. The original OS/2 development team was staffed with ten or so highly competent individuals. Putting aside the commercial success of OS/2 aside I don't think a team of 1000 less competent individuals would have done a better job. More is often less.

Comment: What I guess I'm saying is that this profession is about people and how they are handled in order to produce a result. A young and inexperienced developer should be allowed to grow into his or her shoes and in the processes still retain some genuine passion for the work. Why? Because in the end it will make him or her a better and more competent professional. Reprimands and heavy-handed "advice" will destroy the passion. Besides, as young developers they are being payed a lot less than us older guys and therefore some leeway and understanding is a small price in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @OlofForshell - if you reread my advice carefully, you will see that it is not stated in absolute terms.  And also, note, that I am *primarily* recommending these as *good things to say in a job interview*!  I do also happen to believe them ... while recognizing that they don't apply in all circumstances.  A good Software Engineer knows *when* to ignore the standard advice.

Comment: @OlofForshell - the reason that us older guys get paid more is because we *do* have the wisdom that comes from experience.  And part of what we are paid to do is to *mentor* the young guys.  And that includes pointing out their mistakes and mistaken ideas ... saving them, and their bosses pain in the process.

Comment: The problem is that experience comes from making more or less bad choices and then learning from them. In this respect mentoring young developers is like parenting children. They sometimes need assistance from someone with more experience but most of the time they are more than capable of drawing conclusions and changing their ways all by themselves. In that respect there are very few "mistakes or mistaken ideas." There are situations and lessons to be learned. The "bosses pain"? That's part of the job description and can't be eliminated. If he can't understand people he's in the wrong job.

Comment: @OlofForshell - It seems that you have no sympathy for managers.  So lets recast this in another way.  The problem arises when some junior developer *ignores* best practice, ignores advice and (often) ignore common sense ... and the end result is a disaster.  The common response of the boss is to sack the junior on the grounds that he is incompetent.  If senior developers (like us) can at least tell the junior what best practice is, we are potentially saving him from making a big mistake that will cost him his job.

Comment: @OlofForshell (continued) - In this case, the disaster is going to be a combination of missing a "drop dead" milestone, or producing an "optimized" application that is unmaintainable because of the nature of the "optimizations" that have been applied.

Comment: I've had lots of managers over 30 years and the ones that worked best were those that traded sacking junior developers for loyalty-building activities. In the end, developers didn't want to let the manager down. Maybe it's something Swedish that managers manage, lead and are one of the guys at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

As Stephen C says, "the most efficient way to multiply by 7 may be the multiply operator."

In this paper - [Instruction latencies and throughput for AMD and Intel x86 processors](http://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf) - Torbjörn Granlund of the Royal Institute of Technology in Stockholm shows that an unsigned multiply requires 3/5 clock cycles in 32/64-bit modes on the K10 architecture and 4/4 on Sandy Bridge. If you need to perform multiple multiplies back-to-back the K10 can issue a multiply every/every other clock cycle in 32/64-bit modes. This means that it may work on three multiplies in different stages simultaneously (3/1) and 2.5 (5/2) in 64-bit. Sandy Bridge issues one every other/every clock cycle in 32/64. This means two (4/2) or four (4/1) instructions simultaneously.

Personally, I believe you'll be hard-pressed to better this by a multi-shift sequence. I disagree with Stephen C when he tells you what you should (or shouldn't) do. If everyone did that there'd be no innovations in the software industry.

So: go for it!

Comment: Thanks for the minus, whoever gave it.