# Multiply two numbers without using the "*" operator and bitwise operations

Tags: algorithm

How will you multiply two numbers without using the "*" and bitwise operations in an efficient way?(Just by using operators like +,-,/).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069488/how-can-i-perform-multiplication-without-the-operator

Answer (score 1):

```
a*b == 10^(Log(a*b)) == 10^(Log(a) + Log(b)) == exp(ln(a) + ln(b))
```

where `^` means exponentiation and `Log` is the logarithm with a base of 10

Comment: exp(ln(a) + ln(b)) then, not using a generic exponentiation

Comment: @unkulunkulu Thx. Added it as another transformation

Answer (score 0):

```
multiply(a,b):
      if(a==0) return 0
      r<-0
      while(b/a!=r) r++
      return r
```

Ok, I'm kidding, but you should give more informations about your search: what is an efficient way for you? 
Can you give an approximation of the complexity searched? 
Or do you want the most efficient algorithm?
Because, if you don't precise anything, I can answer too:

```
multiply(a,b):
      r<-0
      while(a!=0)
           r<-r+b
           b<-b-1
      return r
```

Comment: What's the point of the first code sample (which seems to do division)?