# Assembly code computing the product of two integers without using multiplication operators in Linux

Tags: linux, assembly

I am trying to write an assembly code that could compute the product of two integers from the keyboard without using an multiplication operators. I am completely stuck, I am new to assembly language and Linux/C so any advice is appreciated.

Maybe by using a loop of some sort?

Comment: x86 asm duplicate: an answer on [How can I perform multiplication without the '\*' operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2069674).  I assume you're using Linux on an x86 CPU?  It runs on many architectures, all of which have different assembly languages.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use shifting and addition to do this.

Lets say that you are trying to multiply 3 * 3, and we had a 4 bit register.

In binary: 0011 * 0011

if we encounter a 1 we shift right by the value of the index where we found the 1, if we have a zero we don't do anything:

0011

first we have 1, at location 0, so we add the number to an empty register without shifting: we have 0011 so far

then we have another 1, at location 1, we shift the original number 0110, and add it to the previous value 0011

```
0011 + 0110 => 1001 ; since we have all 0's after we are done
```

You need to iterate over the bits of one of the value that you will be multiplying and everytime that you have a 1 apply a shift that will correspond to its location.

Comment: thank you, this helps a bit...my next question would be how do you actually do that as a code? I also read using jump loops can be helpful but I am not sure